# Error while Jenkins is accessing a central Maven repository

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have added a third party library and tried to deploy this in Jenkins. 
The Jenkins instance is trying to look at the central Maven repository instead of the local repository.

But the logfile gives me the following erroneous output:

```
FailedConsole Output

Started by user Diego
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Build Solutions Project\workspace
Checkout:workspace / C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Build Solutions Project\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@9bcb0a
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision b97c0c16f6c100654a6b129c02621a9da823d724 (origin/RefactorCallActivityPage)
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from origin
Commencing build of Revision b97c0c16f6c100654a6b129c02621a9da823d724 (origin/RefactorCallActivityPage)
Checking out Revision b97c0c16f6c100654a6b129c02621a9da823d724 (origin/RefactorCallActivityPage)
Parsing POMs
Modules changed, recalculating dependency graph
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_43/bin/java" -Xdebug -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-agent-1.3.jar;C:\apache-maven-3.0.5\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar" org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main C:\apache-maven-3.0.5 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-2.28.jar" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-1.3.jar" 65215
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BooleanConverter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Build Solutions Project\workspace\pom.xml install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building CommonFrontPage 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ChartDirector/ChartDirector/5.1/ChartDirector-5.1.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.926s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri May 22 13:42:17 BST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Build Solutions Project\workspace\pom.xml to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Build Solutions Project\modules\com.callitautomotive.solutionsweb$CommonFrontPage\builds\2015-05-22_13-42-13\archive\com.callitautomotive.solutionsweb\CommonFrontPage\1.0-SNAPSHOT\CommonFrontPage-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
message : Failed to execute goal on project CommonFrontPage: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.callitautomotive.solutionsweb:CommonFrontPage:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact ChartDirector:ChartDirector:jar:5.1 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
cause : Could not resolve dependencies for project com.callitautomotive.solutionsweb:CommonFrontPage:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact ChartDirector:ChartDirector:jar:5.1 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
Stack trace : 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project CommonFrontPage: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.callitautomotive.solutionsweb:CommonFrontPage:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact ChartDirector:ChartDirector:jar:5.1 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:258)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:201)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
```

Could anyone help me on this, please ?

Comment: The error output is missing, or was it empty on the server?

Comment: i have attached it as an image. Anyways the following is the error:

Comment: Please provide some more insights: 
Does your jenkins run locally or on a build server?
Do you have the artifact in the maven repository, that the mvn used by jenkins uses?
If you have a maven repo (like nexus/artifactory), do you have the artifact there, and is the repository configured in the project?

Comment: Better explanation and cleanup